# How to create copy of audio object

Tags: javascript

My first thought was that copying an audio object would be as simple as copying any other object. Here are three attempts that all return an empty object:

```
const audio = new Audio("test.wav")

console.log(
  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(audio)),
   Object.assign({}, audio), 
   {...audio}
   )
```

https://playcode.io/570724

What am I missing? I'm using react so no solutions the rely on DOM manipulation please.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve by copying it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is to pass it to a child component and update the onended attribute without mutating the original.

Comment: What is the update exactly? What you want to do on audio end?

Comment: It's for a game for kids where they click the image corresponding to the sound they hear. The component receives 20 or so audios objects as props created in the parent component. It also receives an array of around 50 arrays, each corresponding to a "round" of the game containing 5 words. So the .onended has a function depending on whether they are correct or not. The problem is one audio corresponds to both the image they click (which needs the .onended) and the button that plays the sound they have to guess (which shouldnt  have an onended function)

Comment: You can't detect whether image was clicked or button?

Comment: Yes but whatever function has to be run after the audio is played. Is there a way of doing that without using the onended attribute? Or passing a parameter to onended?

Comment: Just mentioning there are libraries like react-sound or react-audio-player or any of the other React wrappers for audio, where you can transparently use the React components.  Although I'd personally still use native APIs, so I can have enough control to make sure it works across platforms (esp. iOS click-event hacks).

Answer (score 0):

[Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) will create a new [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) (DOM element like `document.createElement('audio')`) and you may not copy a DOM element by a method used on regular javascript object; it is like trying to copy `let p = document.querySelector('p');` like this `let p_copy = {...p}`. well it won't work. check the example in snippet below.

```js
const audio = new Audio("http://dl.music2p.ir/1397/12/Sasy%20-%20Gentleman%20(128).mp3");
audio.controls = true;
root.appendChild(audio);

// right way to copy DOM element
let audioCopy1 = audio.cloneNode(true);
root.appendChild(audioCopy1); 

// wrong way
let audioCopy2 = {...audio}; // or other deep copy ways
root.appendChild(audioCopy2); // breaks!
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

And because you said you use react, you should render them dynamically in react friendly manner instead of copying a DOM element and try to use the copies.